# How to fix Missing Operating System after Kali Linux install

Tags: windows-8.1, kali-linux

I hope I didn't screw up my PC but last night.

I installed Kali Linux on my Toshiba L505D-S5965 with Windows 8.1. After I finished I wanted to reboot into my Windows OS, so I rebooted and then the Toshiba logo showed with the insydeH20 bios logo. Then after that it showed

> Missing Operating System

This may be because I finished the installation without GRUB or the LILO bootloader (because it wouldn't install for some reason.)  It said I would have to boot it manually with something called *"vmlinuz"* or something like that.

I'm guessing it has no bootloader. No partitions were wiped so I know Windows is still there.

How can I fix this? If this deals with USB/CD/DVD, I don't have any but I have a 4GB regular size SD card if I can use that.

Comment: This old thread was just bumped by the community bot.  Can you close the loop on the status?  If you solved it, post an answer with your solution and accept it, or if Prasanna's answer was the key, you could accept his.  If it was just overtaken by events, never solved, and no longer reproducible, we can close the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue when the bootloader for Linux has failed to install or when I have formatted the Linux /boot partition by mistake from Windows.
If you would like to boot to Win 8.1 in the first place, then using another PC download Hiren boot CD image. See if you can transfer the contents of our Hiren CD onto your 4 GB SD card.
This makes the 4 GB SD card a bootable one. Boot from the Hiren program from your SD card and open MS DOS or any other DOS utility.
Type `fdisk /mbr`.
This will fix the mbr and let you boot Windows 8.1 first.
How to install Linux boot loader is another subject for discussion - I think.

Comment: I have another laptop, but it doesn't turn on.

Comment: What device are you using to post in superuser.com ?

Comment: My Nintendo 3DS.

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at this. http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/. This can possibly be a solution. Does you Nintendo 3DS has a SD card slot

Comment: Yes, but the Nintendo 3DS can't install .exe files.

Comment: There is very little that we can do now. Let me know if there are any other resources / devices with which u can work.

Comment: Can I use Setup Utility (F2) or Boot Manager (F12)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17818/discussion-between-prasanna-and-kprovost7314).